# SQL Server 2005 migration to new environment SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am new here. I was recently handed a project to create an environment with Windows 2012 and SQL Server 2012. The goal is to take the existing databases in our current environment which is SQL Server 2005 and Windows 2003 platform. I have tried looking for specific whitepapers to doing this or checklists that might exist. What are some of the things I should plan for, can I de-attach a database in the SQL Server 2005 environment. I did check the compatibility version for SQL Server 2005 environment is 90. Any help would be appreciated. I feel as if I might be in over my head.

Comment: (1) backup from SQL Server 2005, (2) copy the `.bak` files to the new server, (3) restore from the  `.bak` file, (4) (optionally) update compatibility level to 110 - **DONE!**

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend the De-attach/attach method.  De-attach/attach method will only work with the database but you will have to manually create the jobs. There will be other issues.