# migrating ms sql database to new server

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2014

Scenario: 
We have MS SQL 2005 installed on a windows 2003 server with 9GB database.
We acquired a new Windows 2012 server and installed MS SQL 2014 on it.

My expertise level:
Partial knowledge of SQL server and databases

What I need:
I am given a task to migrate the 9GB database (SQL 2005) to a SQL 2014..
DB names and all should be identical to old one..

I would like to know the steps involved from experts, so I can achieve this job w/o any issues.

I am thinking of below steps:

1) Full Backup of 2005 database...
2) Create a new database with same name on the new server
3) Restore the full backup (taken on old server) on the new server
4) Change the compatibility level to suit to the new sql server

pls. let me know if this works or do I need to follow other approach.
any queries, pls. feel free to ask.

sql_learner

Comment: You may also want to post this on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: I tried this and unable to get through....would appreciate some other approach from experts

Comment: That approach will work, step 2 is redundant as you can directly restore without a pre-existing database.  Also, don't forget you'll need to migrate your logins and any other server objects that are required (like linked servers if you have any).

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `Copy Database Wizard`,The `Copy Database Wizard` lets you move or copy databases and their objects easily from one server to another.
Check [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/hh831725.aspx)

Comment: Hi Arun, thank you... the new server is not yet in the network, so cannot choose destination server. It is more like migrating the old DB on to a the new server, but like on to a stand-alone pc as of now...once we achieve this, we will detach the old server and deploy the new one....

Comment: Then i think the best way is take a backup of your db and Restore it in your new sqlserver 2014 enviornment

Answer (score 0):

I tried below steps and it worked w/o any issues...

1) Full Backup of 2005 database... 2) Copied backup data on to the new server 3) Restored the full backup (taken on old server) on the new server 4) Change the compatibility level to suit to the new sql server (120).

The above steps worked for AdventureWorks sample database for me...
Before I go ahead with the original DB, I need to know if what I did is correct or am I missing something.

Raj

Answer (score 0):

upon further search on this forum, i found below link with a scenario similar to mine and seems what i did is the correct way...

just in case someone lands here, they can quickly check this link...

[SQL Server 2005 migration to new environment SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23899116/sql-server-2005-migration-to-new-environment-sql-server-2012?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any database users setup that you will also need to transfer? If so, you will need to reset these up at the instance level SSMS > Security.
Also don't forget to transfer any maintenance plans or jobs from the old to the new server (such as backup / defrag / DBCC checks).

Comment: Hi Richard, thank you for your support. We do not have any users on the database, it is used as a backend for a CRM software (installed on the server). We do have a maintenance plan, was not sure we can transfer it, thank you for pointing to it. I was thinking of recreating the same on the new server.